# Show that there exist a noncommutative ring (with identity) of order $p^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let p be a fixed prime. Show that there exist a noncommutative ring (with identity) of order $p^3$.

**Remark**I was able to $p = 2$:  $U_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ - the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But where $p>2$ is not worth.

Comment: Hint for (a): Show if the $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: See [Ring of order $p^2$ is commutative.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305512/ring-of-order-p2-is-commutative?rq=1) and [Noncommutative ring of order $np^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451069/noncommutative-ring-of-order-np2?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the ring  $$R=\{A\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbf{F}_p)\mid A_{21}=0\}$$ consisting of matrices with $(2,1)$ entry zero. As sum and product of upper tringular matrices is again upper triangular, and as $I\in R$ this is  a subring. As there are no other conditions on the entries it indeed has $p^3$ elements. Definitely we can find two such matrices not commuting with each other.